# Alpha Channel in Hex-Code at 99 % still pretty "see-through"

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, alpha

I have created an alert with an activity indicator on it. This alert is just 1 % see through and 99 % black. This is achieved with a boxview as a background, with an alpha channel on its color:

```
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="#99000000" CornerRadius="20"/>
```

As my understanding goes, that means that 99 is the amount is solidness and the 000000 after is the color.
If I go, say #05000000, I get a slightly visible black rectangle since it is 95% seethrough and only 5 percent solid.

But the result of above code is:

[image]

So, as you can see, the text behind the rectangle is still pretty visible. No way this is 99 % black and only 1 % visible.

Am I maybe understanding the alpha channel wrong? How would I achieve even MORE blackness and less see through?

Thank you!

Comment: alpha channel it's hex too, not percentage, the closer you get to FF more visible the color is, getting closer to 00 make it more transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like HTML, XF uses **hexadecimal** color values that range from 00 to FF.

```
BackgroundColor="#99000000"
```

is NOT 99% Alpha, it is 99/FF ==> 99/255, or 38%

Comment: That was coorect. Thank you!